# Django form wizard with Ajax

Tags: ajax, django, django-formwizard, formwizard

I'm trying to use form wizard through ajax. I have a separated template that first is loaded when a user want to start using the form. And then is reloaded through ajax until it's completed.

First ajax call to load the form:

```
$('#create-modal').click(function(){
   $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url:"/create/",
        data:{
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
        },
        success: function(data){
            $('#creation').html(data);
        },
        dataType: 'html'
    });
});
```

Here it is the ajax call to reload the submits:

```
$('#creation').on('submit', '#creation-form' , function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var fd = new FormData($('#creation-form').get(0));
    $.ajax({
      url: '/create/',
      data: fd,
      type: "POST",
      success: function(data){
            $('#creation').html(data);
          },
      processData: false,
      contentType: false
    });
});
```

The form can be completed and save into the database just fine but what the previous step button isn't working, it just keeps going foward to the form when I click it.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" aria-hidden="true" type="submit" name="wizard_goto_step" value="{{ wizard.steps.prev }}">Previous</button>
```

and all other variants, last, first...

I'm not including all the code because when I call the url directly from the browser the previous button works just fine. That is when I call it form /create/ rather than the url where the ajax are.

Request headers for both ajax (not working) and without ajax (working). http://snipt.org/AOC9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used `FormData` so I don't know if that's the source of the problem or not. Anyway I would recommend you to change the code to somewhat like this:

```
$('#creation').on('submit', '#creation-form' , function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var post_data = $(this).serialize();
    console.log('POST data:' + post_data);

    $.ajax({
      url: '/create/',
      data: post_data,
      type: "POST",
      success: function (resp) {
          console.log(resp);
          $('#creation').html(resp);
      },
      error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          console.log(jqXHR);
          console.log(textStatus);
          console.log(errorThrown);
      }
      processData: false,
      contentType: false
    });
});
```

If it doesn't work, check the console and you will know why it fails yourself.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I'm kind of new at this to figure out the problem. I think that I'm missing something, the second step form is displaying two button, one forward and one backwards. But my jQuery is not making any difference on the submit (I also tried to make a second 'on' function with the second function). I'm comparing both form one loaded by ajax and one directly from the url, and both are the same. How is the previous button is telling Django what I want? I don't get it even through the direct url, without using ajax. All the post data is the same.

Comment: So I would recommend you use 'click' event rather than 'submit'. You can add some id to your button `<button id="js-nextBtn" class="btn btn-primary" ...>Next</button>` then in jQuery use `$('#creation').on('click', '#js-nextBtn', function (e) ...`. The rest should be pretty much the same.

Comment: It isn't working either. Maybe the session data is the problem, because it's not updating?

Comment: Check your console for any error. Then check Network tab in Firebug/Chrome dev tools to see if the ajax actually sent any data.

Comment: No error, and yes the ajax is sending data. It's only a problem with the previous button, because you can complete all the form and successfully create an object into the database. Here I copied both request headers, the first one works, the second one (ajax) doesn't. http://snipt.org/AOC9.

Comment: Could you edit your question and add code of both ajax requests?

Comment: Edited. The ajax request when clicking the prev button it's exactly the same but the first line as you write in a previous comment.